# Securing user's email in parse.com + web hosting

Tags: javascript, security, parse-platform

I have an app built on top of parse. The app design is such that users know each other's username.

I'd like to create a web interface to the app. However, because user data has to be readable to everyone, email addresses can be found/collected.

I know it's a long standing question, has anyone found a solution in securing users email on parse.com + web hosting ?

In my case, cloud code doesn't help, as 1) prevents caching on the client side. 2) because user names are required, this would mean replacing all of PArseQueries by cloud code.

Has anyone tried to create an intermediate web service to work as a reverse-proxy in case of parse + web hosting ?

to parse: if user's email were md5'ed after registration, and their real value stored in another class, what would be the best approach to

- make parse's email checks against duplicated entries work again ? User:beforeSave ?
- make parse's email-reset / email verification work again ?

thanks !

Note: just in case, if there's someone from Parse around, bearing all the noise over privacy, it would be nice to have a native parse class where personal data is stored, and only accessible by its owner OR make the email/FB/TWt data not fetchable unless the MasterKey is used.

Note:the current design issue is that authentication credentials (username and password) are stored in the same class as the email...

Comment: Why does the user data need to be readable to everyone? Do you have to use the email field on the User table, or could you have another table hold that data and lock that table down more?

Comment: it needs to be readable to everyone so that anyone can know each other's name. The mail is seldom used, access can be made separately if need be. I see your point though, it's down to who's going to cope with the _User table design. That being said, it's not exactly a permanent solution. _User has native properties that make it useful, and important when managing content created by users. Using say myUser has a replacement adds a very very significant amount of work, and potential side effects. I'm disappointed that parse.com never tried to address this problem.

Comment: @TimothyWalters just out of curiosity, have you already implemented a solution like the one you suggested ? if yes, any caveats, pitfalls ? I'm still leaning towards a reverse-proxy, because the problem is mostly on the Web hosting part, but your option has the nice feature to work for iOS and Android (but again, there's a lot of coding efforts to be made, and code won't be transparent).

Comment: Yes, though I don't allow anon access, but I limit info that others can see to a "public" class, and keep the rest private and locked down to the owner. It means moving some queries to cloud code and using the master key, but the system is very secure and privacy isn't breached, which should always be #1 priority I think.

Comment: Hi thanks ! just a question : if a piece of user-content, like a public comment is created, what pointer do you use to reference that comment ? the _User class or the class that you created that acts as a replacement ? Does that mean that for every occurrence of the original _User class, you replaced it with your *myUser* class ? Moving queries to cloud code defeats caching, was that a problem in your case ?

Comment: Yes I link to the public user class, since I want to display public user information anyway. When I need more for some reason I use a cloud function to get everything as one big JSON object, restricted to just the bare minimum fields needed. I verify permissions inside the cloud code before returning any data. You need to think of where/why/how-much sensitive data you need, and you can still implement a cache keyed off ID.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. Of the top of my head, I can't see issues with this approach, besides the high profile job to rework my code. that's going to be a pain in the neck really. Why Parse.com never hinted to this is beyond me (albeit I could have thought about it too). I'll see if I can get a hold of a parse guy on google forum, see if I can have his pointers. May be a fully detailed post would help other dev too. So the permission you set on the _User table are something like admin role = rw/find/get/update owner=rw/find/get/update users = 0. Thanks Tim !

Comment: Hi @TimothyWalters , a quick question to you, is there a way to secure the Installation class or is it a lost cause ?

Comment: Ok, I missed that point : I add this for sake of exhaustivity. Installation class has it's own security mechanism, tied to the device, and Parse internal code

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/parse-developers/security/parse-developers/xbvO9pD9xKI/lEsF3zOID0wJ

so it looks fine.